# VBA FreeFile greater than 255

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I have been doing an worksheet with macros for finding a few parameters and information in general from a bunch of files and publishing the information into another sheet. Well... that was working great until this week where people started to use the excell macros for opening more than 255 files( between 300 and 450 )

`

```
   Do While Worksheets(P1).Cells(j, 4).Value <> ""
        OpenFile = Worksheets(P1).Cells(6, 2).Value & "\" & Worksheets(P1).Cells(j, 4).Value
        'Worksheets(P2).Cells(z, 1) = OpenFile
        i = 1
       
 lArquivo = FreeFile
        Open OpenFile For Input As lArquivo
        Do While Not EOF(lArquivo)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
```

`

Well, this is just a part of a bigger code... but the point is, I open those many files and when it's more than 255 I cannot use the freefile function due it goes only from 1-255.
How it is possible to solve that? any strategy that I can to go with? Couldn't think about anything.

Thank you

Comment: `FreeFile(0)` returns a number in the range 1-255, `FreeFile(1)` returns a number in the 256-511 range. From  official docs. Maybe you should read files into memory one by one and do the processing?

Comment: Do you really need that many files open at the same time?

Comment: In a nutshell, use `Close lArquivo` when done with a file and you'll only ever need one number.

Comment: I thought to use freefile(0) and freefile(1), but I was not able to do something "smart" with it, maybe I have to use something like a if/case for opening 1-255 and later 256+ ? Not sure.

Comment: Yes, I really have to open all of than. But as the other friend suggested but still have to try. @VBasic2008 you telling me something like... for every FreeFile ( first file opened, value 1 ) right after I finish reading it , I close it at the end of the my EOF(Larquivo) ?

Comment: Yes, probably after `Loop`, you will use `Close larquivo`, and in the next iteration, `larquivo = FreeFile` will again determine the first available number which will be the same (probably #1, but that is not of your concern). You don't have to specify it, but you'll know that it won't grow especially not to such absurd numbers.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I've give a quicky try, but somehow as LArquivo = Freefile will always have a value '1'  it only do the findings inside the "do While Not EOF(larquivo)" for the first file in my file list with more than 400 files listed. I'll try to debug this during the week but seems like I have to have the value of LArquivo = file number ascending for this to work.

Comment: Just to inform you guys, the strategy of closing the file right after finishing the EOF loop is valid. My problem was that I was using the FreeFile value to publish the variables into another spreedsheet. Now I created a new variable for doing that and all doing fine.